# How Would I Style Dynamically Created jQuery UI elements using CSS3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I don't really know how to explain this, but I want to apply different color styles to dynamically created jQuery UI buttons. I think the `:nth-child(x)` or `nth-of-type(x)` would help, but neither has worked yet. Am I putting them in the right order, or is there something else that would help?

**My JS:**

```
var listContent = '<div id="PlayerPicker">';
$(xml).find('Character').each(function () {
listContent += '<input type="radio" id="RB_' + $(this).attr('First') +
    $(this).attr('Last') + '" name="player" class="ui-button-text"
    style="background-color: transparent;"><label for="RB_' +
    $(this).attr('First') + $(this).attr('Last') + '">' + $(this).attr('Title')
    + ' ' + $(this).attr('First') + ' ' + $(this).attr('Middle').charAt(0) + '.
    ' + $(this).attr('Last') + '</label>';
});
listContent += '</div>';
$('#Wrapper').html(listContent);
$('#PlayerPicker').buttonset();
```

**My CSS:**

```
#PlayerPicker .ui-button-text {
    background: #ff3d3d;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, hsl(240,100%,62%) 1%, hsl(240,100%,15%) 48%, hsl(240,100%,62%) 49%, hsl(240,100%,15%) 68%, hsl(240,100%,50%) 95%, hsl(240,97%,24%) 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, hsl(240,100%,62%) 1%,hsl(240,100%,15%) 48%,hsl(240,100%,62%) 49%,hsl(240,100%,15%) 68%,hsl(240,100%,50%) 95%,hsl(240,97%,24%) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, hsl(240,100%,62%) 1%,hsl(240,100%,15%) 48%,hsl(240,100%,62%) 49%,hsl(240,100%,15%) 68%,hsl(240,100%,50%) 95%,hsl(240,97%,24%) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ff3d3d', endColorstr='#780202',GradientType=0 );
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 99px;
    font-size: 14pt;
}

#PlayerPicker:nth-child(2) .ui-button-text {
    background: #ff3d3d;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, hsl(330,100%,62%) 1%, hsl(330,100%,15%) 48%, hsl(330,100%,62%) 49%, hsl(330,100%,15%) 68%, hsl(330,100%,50%) 95%, hsl(330,97%,24%) 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, hsl(330,100%,62%) 1%,hsl(330,100%,15%) 48%,hsl(330,100%,62%) 49%,hsl(330,100%,15%) 68%,hsl(330,100%,50%) 95%,hsl(330,97%,24%) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, hsl(330,100%,62%) 1%,hsl(330,100%,15%) 48%,hsl(330,100%,62%) 49%,hsl(330,100%,15%) 68%,hsl(330,100%,50%) 95%,hsl(330,97%,24%) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ff3d3d', endColorstr='#780202',GradientType=0 );
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 99px;
}
```

**UPDATE**: [Here's my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Shortstuff81000/buv8g8c3/8/), @jmargolisvt. The JS has been simplified, but the CSS is the same.

Comment: Please provide a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) of what you've got so far.

Comment: Have you tried `#PlayerPicker .ui-button-text:nth-child(2)` rather than `#PlayerPicker:nth-child(2) .ui-button-text`?

Comment: @nnnnnn Yeah. multiple times. It doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the HTML you created with the JavaScript and you can see that you need the  styling set on the label tag.

```
#PlayerPicker .ui-button-text label {...} and
#PlayerPicker .ui-button-text:checked label {...}
```

Comment: I tried that in my fiddle; it reset the buttons to their default theme. I think it's because `.ui-button-text` already deals with the label. Thanks for the advice, though.